# JQuery Traversing inside div's

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

```
<div class="tasksMobile" id="headerDTMobile2">
<div class="divSubTaskMobile" id="divDefaultTask4">
<div class="divSubTaskMobile" id="divDefaultTask3">
<div class="divSubTaskMobile" id="divDefaultTask2">
<div class="tasksMobile" id="headerDTMobile3">
```

This query does not give html of three `<div>` elements inside of `#headerDTMobile2`:

```
$("#headerDTMobile2").nextUntil(".tasksMobile").html()
```

Comment: try using next() instead of nextUntil

Comment: Are there any closing `</div>` tags?

Answer (score -1):

Notice this note from jQuery docs:

> As of jQuery 1.6, A DOM node or jQuery object, instead of a selector, may be passed to the .nextUntil() method.

Which version of jQuery are you using.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I can't post comments on the question.